# How to use dtosmote 1.0.3(PyPI) for my dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pypi, smote

To tackle the Class-imbalance problem, SMOTE is a very well-known criterion.
I have read the theory. Now to get the feel, I am doing the practical implication.

```
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE 

X, y = make_classification(n_classes=2, class_sep=2,
weights=[0.1, 0.9], n_informative=3, n_redundant=1, flip_y=0,
n_features=20, n_clusters_per_class=1, n_samples=1000, random_state=10)
print('Original dataset shape %s' % Counter(y))

sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)
# sm =  delaunaySMOTE
X_res, y_res = sm.fit_resample(X, y)
print('Resampled dataset shape %s' % Counter(y_res))
```

The above code gives me this result.

[image]

---

[Then I come across this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8489411). To implement this I saw their Github repo. And I found a PyPI package (not well documented) [Package](https://pypi.org/project/dtosmote/). I want to incorporate this to my previous code to see how effective is this. Hence I tried in this way

```
sm =  delaunaySMOTE(random_state=42)
```

But it is giving me errors. How to fix this?

[image]

```
NameError: name 'delaunaySMOTE' is not defined
```

although I have installed it.

```
 !pip install dtosmote
```

---

**Solution**

```
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from dtosmote.dto_smote import DTO
X, y = make_classification(n_classes=2, class_sep=2,
weights=[0.1, 0.9], n_informative=3, n_redundant=1, flip_y=0,
n_features=20, n_clusters_per_class=1, n_samples=1000, random_state=10)
print('Original dataset shape %s' % Counter(y))

# sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)
# sm =  delaunaySMOTE(random_state=42)
sm = DTO('teste1','solid_angle',7.5)
X_res, y_res = sm.fit_resample(X, y)
print('Resampled dataset shape %s' % Counter(y_res))
```

Comment: How to fix WHAT errors? Please show the full text of the error messages.

Comment: Name `delaunaySMOTE` is not defined, Where did you see the function in the installed package?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors).

Comment: Have you checked the package? See there nothing is documented. I am not able to use that package properly. Hence posted here to get help!

Comment: There is an example in the repository: https://github.com/carvalhoamc/DTOSMOTE#dto-smote . There is a test: https://github.com/carvalhoamc/DTOSMOTE/blob/master/dtosmote/test.py

Comment: THANKS I have got it. One thing I would like to ask, do you understand what is the 1st parameter('teste1' ) stands for ? I have no idea :(

Comment: From https://github.com/carvalhoamc/DTOSMOTE#dto-smote : "Here, we have three parameters: **'test1' is a temp filename** for dtosmote." Emphasize mine